# ibv_create_qp failure: is there a kernel parameter I can increase?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, network-programming, infiniband

I'm using an acceleration library for my networking card to get kernel bypass while reading UDP packets. It works well, though when I subscribe beyond a certain number of sockets, the library calls into `ibv_create_qp` and fails with errno = ENOMEM. Clearly this is not about user memory, as there are tens of free gigabytes available.

I assume this is some kind of kernel resource, possibly buffers, possibly something else, that's being exhausted. Can anyone point me in the direction of a kernel parameter I can increase to get more of whatever this is?

Comment: *"I assume ..."* -- Based on what evidence?  Did you try a web search?  E.G. http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.network.openfabrics.enterprise/5351 and https://hpcrdm.lbl.gov/pipermail/upc-users/2011-July/000482.html

Comment: Wow, a sarcastic response and a downvote. For the record, I did google it; I did find those results and others; they don't solve the problem or explain what it might be. Just like you. But you got to take a shot at me for using the words "I assume" when they were in fact the correct ones to use given the situation. Thanks for being a constructive community participant.

Comment: It's downvoted because your post meets the first criterion: *"does not show any research effort"*.  All I read is "got error, make WAG, ask XY question for help".

Comment: So if I had typed the characters "I googled and found nothing" it would have been OK with you? Super important to me to meet all your semantic criteria.